# tCosmosDBConnection component is not showing in Talend Open Studio for Data Integration

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, talend, data-migration

Im using Talend Open Studio fro Data Integration Version 7.1.1. I need to Connect Azure Database to data extract and data upload from Talend to our SQL databases. I have gone through below link to connect to Azure cosmos dbs.

https://help.talend.com/r/OgamG5JTIU2aMhx2HjGp8g/L1KG9WTDgOCS8RO9RzqIQw

But in my Talend DB Connection I can find the any CosmosDBconnection type or component. Even I tried to search in packages but didnt find. Could someone tell me how install or enable CosmosDBConnection or how to connect to Cosmos database using Talend.

Answer (score 0):

As per Talend documentation -

> tCosmosDBConnection
>
> Creates a connection to a CosmosDB database and reuse that connection in other components.

> tCosmosDBConnection Standard properties
>
> These properties are used to configure tCosmosDBConnection running in the Standard Job framework.
>
> The Standard tCosmosDBConnection component belongs to the Cloud and
> the Databases families.
>
> The component in this framework is available in all Talend products
> with Big Data.

As you are using Talend Open Studio for Data Integration Version 7.1.1, you are not able to see these specific components in your palette.
Also, you might want to check out Project Settings -> Designer -> Palette settings and check out the components that are available and selected for your studio.